# How to use the order and group by in ng-repeat with data format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, material-design, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a json as

```js
[{
  "type" : "visible_product",
  "description" : "asdjkjasd asdak",
  "launch_date" : "2015-12-03T10:42:34.972Z"
 }, {
  "type" : "non_visible_product",
  "description" : "askjd asdkasd askdjkasd",
  "launch_date" : "2015-12-03T10:44:34.972Z"
 }, {
  "type" : "durable_product",
  "description" : "asdjkjasd asdak",
  "launch_date" : "2015-12-04T10:41:34.972Z"
 }, {
  "type" : "non_durable_product",
  "description" : "asdjkjasd asdak",
  "launch_date" : "2015-12-04T10:44:34.972Z"
 }, {
  "type" : "visible_product",
  "description" : "asdjkjasd asdak",
  "launch_date" : "2015-12-04T10:44:30.972Z"
 }, {
  "type" : "visible_product",
  "description" : "asdjkjasd asdak",
  "launch_date" : "2015-12-06T10:44:34.972Z"
 }]
```

I am displaying the data as list in descending sorting order

```html
<md-list-item class="md-2-line my-list" 
              ng-repeat="item in my_json_data | orderBy:'-launch_date'" 
              ng-class="{launch_sel: $index == selected}">
  <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column" >
    <a class="md-accent url-no-decoration"  href=""
       ng-click="myfunction(item.type, $index)" style="cursor:pointer">
      <h3> {{ item.type }} </h3>
      <p> {{ item.description}} </p>
      <p>{{ item.launch_date | date:'dd-MMM-yy HH:mm'}}</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</md-list-item>
```

When I tried to display the data based on grouping on date its not working.
List should be sorted and grouped as 2 data for day 6, next there should be no day 5 as json has no data in the list,
then day 4 and then day 3.

```html
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in my_json_data | orderBy:'-launch_date'">
  <h3>Group name: {{ key }}</h3>
  <md-list-item class="md-2-line my-list" 
                ng-repeat="item in my_json_data | orderBy:'-launch_date'" 
                ng-class="{launch_sel: $index == selected}">
    <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column" >
      <a class="md-accent url-no-decoration"  href=""
         ng-click="myfunction(item.type, $index)" style="cursor:pointer">
        <h3> {{ item.type }} </h3>
        <p> {{ item.description}} </p>
        <p>{{ item.launch_date | date:'dd-MMM-yy HH:mm'}}</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </md-list-item>
</div>
```

How to display data as

```
Dec 6 
   //data 1
Dec 4
   //data 2
   //data 3
   //data 4
Dec 3
   //data 5
   //data 6
```

Comment: Just a side-note: you have two `ng-repeat` repeating over same array: `ng-repeat="(key, value) in my_json_data"` and `ng-repeat="item in my_json_data"` in the last example.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually **quite straightforward**. Simply use the `groupBy` directive from the `angular.filter` module:

```
<div ng-repeat="(date, entries) in data | groupBy: 'launch_date'">
```

Here's a [working JSFiddle lin](http://jsfiddle.net/42yazakf/7/)k illustrating my solution using your sample data.

Comment: Thanks ... My JSON.parse(my_json_data) is not working ; ease its working fine if I pass the string directly to it ..

Comment: In my object I am getting 
[Resource, Resource, Resource, Resource, Resource, Resource, Resource, Resource, Resource, Resource, $promise: Promise, $resolved: true] is this $promise and $resolved causing error as it is giving me duplicate value

Comment: It works fine but it is using date time istead of just time